# What's the difference between Box2D and tweening?

Tags: animation, box2d, tweening

It seems like Box2D can be used to move sprites across the screen, so how does this differ from tweening? Is it that Box2D is for physical collision detections and tweening is just animations?

Comment: -1 Have you heard of Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box2d vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweening

Answer (score 0):

Box2D is a physics library for 2d environments. Tweening is the process of gradually interpolating values.

Tweening itself is not fundamentally for animation, though it is widely used in animation for smooth transitions.